# AsyncStorage functions just producing garbage in react native

Tags: react-native, jsx

So I implemented this code in a file from the [react native docs](https://reactnative.dev/docs/asyncstorage).

```
class Storage {

    //store data in 'key'

    store = async (key, data) => {
        try {
            await AsyncStorage.setItem(key, data);
        } catch (error) {
            // Error saving data
            console.log(error.message);
        }
    };


    retrieve = async (key) => {
        try {
            const   value = await AsyncStorage.getItem(key);
            if (value !== null) {
                // We have data!!
                console.log(value);
            }
        } catch (error) {
            // Error retrieving data
            console.log(error.message);
        }
    };

}
```

And this in other I want to use to actually store and retrieve the variables:

```
strg.store('test', 'testing');
testing =  strg.retrieve('test');
```

I kept getting an error but then looking it up here I figured out my storage output was an object and not a string as I expected. So I used `JSON.stringify(***)` and this gibberish came out instead of a "testing".

```sh
{"_40":0, "_65":0, "_55":null,"_72":null}
```

*edit*: I figure out how to use the console to debug and I found out the 'testing' was inside the promise object that comes out of my function. I read a little about async functions and now I want to know how do I extract the values from the promises?

Comment: console.log(value); does this print the correct value ?

Comment: I got this from the docs I don't know yet how to use the console

Answer (score 0):

Your store and retrieve functions are asyn so you have to use await until the actual task is complete.

```js
    So the code should be like below.
    await strg.store('test', 'testing');
    const testing = await strg.retrieve('test');
```

The garbage value is a promise so it will be something like the object you got.

If you return value like this you will retrieve it from outside.

```js
           const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem(key);
            if (value !== null) {
                // We have data!!
                console.log(value);

            return value;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

This happened because you are using AsyncStorage - an asynchronous storage system. You have to wait until it done retrieve data from storage to get the proper data.

I think there are two correct ways to get data from your implementation:

Use async with your container function name & await with your function called

```
async function getData() {
    ....
    let data = await strg.retrieve('test');
    console.log("data", data);
}
```

or simple use `.then()`:

```
strg.retrieve('test').then((data) => {
    console.log("data", data);
    // Handle retrieved data
});
```

Hope that help. :)

Comment: But they are   here:  ' store = async (key, data) => {'
 and here' await AsyncStorage.setItem(key, data);'

Comment: No no, you must put `await` in front of your store function caller, cause the store func is asynchronous too.

Comment: Like this: `await strg.store('test', 'testing');`

Comment: I tried that but the function it's in(construtor(props)) can't be async. I tried using the then method too but I don't know how to retrieve the data to another variable outside the function. The console.log works fine for inside the then

Comment: You shouldn't add this function in constructor. in fact, i think you should not put anything in constructor instead of initialize state. You should put the function call in `componentDidMount` function if you want to call this fnc when screen is init.

Answer (score 0):

This is how i did it and it works like a charm

```
import { AsyncStorage } from 'react-native';

module.exports = {
    retrieve: async (value) => {
        try {
            let data = await AsyncStorage.getItem(value);
            return data;
        } catch (err) {
            return err;
        }
    },
    store: async (key, value) => {
        try {
            // stringify the value since value can only be string.
            if (typeof (value) === 'object')
                value = JSON.stringify(value)
            return await AsyncStorage.setItem(key, value);
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err)
            return err;
        }
    }
}
```